# How to hide my firefox addon source as my complete source with even folder structure is shown in firefox addon page under version information.

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have recently developed a firefox addon, which is accepted by the mozilla reviewers. But once my adon is accepted and available in the gallery, I can see that my entire source with even folder structure is shown under the version information.

Can you please help me out how to hide the source from users ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's open source stuff. Even if you hide it there, users can download your add-on right click and open in notepad to view source. You can obfuscate, but people can just un-obfuscate.  I tihnk this open source is good good for safety etc. But people have their reasons to hide code, but not possible in addons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the "View the source" under "Version Information"?

If that is the case, then
- go to Addon's edit page
- Technical Details
- View Source?
- Deselect "This add-on's source code is publicly viewable."
- Save Changes

Comment: Yes. That solved my problem. Thanks a lot. I am waiting to add my first add-on to firefox from long time, but didn't because of this. you made my day. Thank you :)